# Fit Images of different sizes in specific size div

Tags: html, css

I have different size images say (1920 by 1080).

I want to fit this image in an div having styles
I see the css file in which styles are given as

```
.detail-img{ width:100%; max-height:350px; overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:30px;}
.detail-img img, .detail-img-a img{width:100%;}
.detail-img-a{ width:100%; margin-bottom:15px;}
```

In html page div is like

```
<div class="detail-img">
     <img  src="<%= @event.avatar.url %>">
</div>
```

original image is

[image]

But it displays as
[image]

Is there a way to fit this my div?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set max-width for the image

```
  .detail-img img{
      max-width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: I updated the question with styles given in css file, kinly have a look

Comment: My div almost take 9 columns of bootstrap screen, but with max-width:100%, it makes image size to almost 1/4th of size I need

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal You have given 100% width for the .detail-img container So this and image will occupy the full width. Try give a fixed width such as 500px;  see here - https://jsfiddle.net/4xp4Lp9t/

Comment: it works when width is 500px but when I set 1000px, same issue again

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal In that case, you have to explicitly set with for the image. that is, img{ width: 500 px; }